# Why does cocoapods 0.36.0 have pod classes each folder?

Tags: cocoapods, subspec

I upgrade cocoapods 0.36 version and pod install. The result was the  below picture:

[image http://i3.tietuku.com/8bae565e19ed8cc6.jpg](http://i3.tietuku.com/8bae565e19ed8cc6.jpg)

Subfolder more pod classes folder. This is cocopods' latest update?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include any images.

Comment: @GoBusto I have not enough reputation for it.

Comment: You can still include [links to images](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69) though, even if you can't include them directly.

Comment: Remove "s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes'".

Comment: @gagarwal thank's for your help,but it's not working.

Comment: @gagarwal
just s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'

Answer (score 0):

i found this's way work.

```
 s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
```